How to sum a series of named ranges in Google Sheet
In a Google Sheet, I have two sheets, Diary and Food List.
The Food List looks like:

I defined Rice and Tomato as named ranges which span from column B to F.
The diary looks like:

I want to add the information associated to each named range, Calory, Fat, ... ., and show them in columns B to F per date.
How can I do that?

Food List is your lookup table, Diary has the daily totals by category (eg. cals, fat, carbs, etc.), but you are missing a Food Eaten table that logs each food item consumed and their weight.
For example, Items Eaten would need to include at a minimum Date, Food, Portion, but it could also include additional fields such as Time, Notes, Meal, etc.
Food Eaten is the data that Diary will total up using the lookup table in Food List.
Formula
You could use a formula like the following in Diary!A1 to calculate the daily totals:
={"Date", 'Food List'!B1:F1;
  SORT(
    QUERY(
      QUERY(
        BYROW('Food Eaten'!A2:C, LAMBDA(r, 
          {INDEX(r,,1), 
           IFNA(VLOOKUP(
             INDEX(r,,2), 'Food List'!A:F, {2,3,4,5,6})*INDEX(r,,3)/100)})),
        "Select Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4), SUM(Col5), SUM(Col6)
         Where Col1 is not Null Group by Col1",), "Offset 1",))}

BYROW  IFNA  INDEX  LAMBDA  QUERY  SORT  SUM  VLOOKUP
Explanation

The core of the formula is a BYROW function that passes the range 'Food  Eaten'!A2:C, row by row, into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in r.
For each r, the LAMBDA's formula returns a single row array where,

Col1 is the value from Col1 of r, either a date or an empty value, returned using INDEX.
VLOOKUP is not natively an array function; however, it behaves as one when nested within one (SORT in this case). It returns a 5-column array populated with the values from columns {2,3,4,5,6} of the row in Food List that matches the food in Col 2 of r, or empty values if not matched.
A new array is returned by multiplying each value in VLOOKUP's array by Col3 of r  divided by 100 (per 100g). Again, returning an array is possible only because this calculation is  nested within an array function (SORT).


Once the last r has been processed by the LAMBDA, the result is a multi-row array containing populated and empty rows.
QUERY is used to return the SUM of each of Cols2-6, aggregated by date (Col1), including only rows where Col1 is not Null/blank.
The QUERY's result is nested in another QUERY that uses Offset 1 to drop the row of labels created by the previous aggregation.
This array is nested in SORT with no arguments which defaults to Col1 ascending.
Lastly, a label row is added that uses the string "date" for Col1, and the labels from Cols2-6 of Food List for the remaining columns.

Sample Sheets Data
'Diary'
Formula in A1




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Date [formula here]
Calories
Fat g
Protein g
Carbs g
Salt mg


2
2024 October 05
717
  1
21
160
208


3
2024 October 06
408
30
34
    1
688



'Food Eaten'




A
B
C




1
Date
Food
Portion g


2
2024 October 05
Tomato
120


3
2024 October 05
Rice
175


4
2024 October 05
Dark Rye
32


5
2024 October 06
Egg
50


6
2024 October 06
Tuna
75


7
2024 October 06
Cheddar
67



'Food List' (per 100 g)




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Name
Calories
Fat g
Protein g
Carbs g
Salt mg


2
Cheddar
406
34
20
  1
644


3
Dark Rye
259
  3
  8
48
603


4
Egg
143
13
13
  1
142


5
Rice
350
    -
10
80
    5


6
Tomato
  18
    -
  1
  4
    5


7
Tuna
  86
  1
19
    -
247 mg




Thanks! Is there a way to show an error when the eaten food is not found in Food List?

is there a way to show an error when the eaten food is not found" Yes,  you'd need to decide whether to display that in Food Eaten and/or Diary and what you actually want to display. eg. Highlight with conditional format, helper column with  some value(s), etc. You could try something and if you run into problems post another question.

Thank you for for explanation! I could not find your explanation in Google Sheet documentation, that is using Index or ArrayFormula arround the Vlookup to get an array as output. Could you please point me to the documentation where this is explained so I can learn more on my own? I'v found Google Sheet's doc really disorganized!

I updated the answer with an explanation and replaced INDEX with SORT as it's shorter  I'm not aware of Google documentation specifically about this however many non-array functions become array functions in that way.  e.g. INDEX(IF(ISODD(A2:A10),"odd","even"))  I'm resistant to writing ARRAYFORMULA because it is so long. Similarly where possible I'll use , instead of ,0 and 1 instead of true etc. There's a lot of undocumented info I've learned from more experienced users on this site.
